# Custom Post Type with two custom taxonomy search by post name and taxonomy's name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, autosuggest

Custom Post Type with two custom taxonomy search by post name and taxonomy's name

I want to search by "post title" then autosuggestion will be show post title list.
or search both "taxonomy's" name then will be show *taxonomy's list* **not post title**

How could I do that?
Any help is appreciated

PHP code:

```php
function title_filter( $where, &$wp_query ){
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $search_term = $wp_query->get( 's' ) ) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( $wpdb->esc_like( $search_term ) ) . '%\'';
    }
    return $where; } function search_auto_sugg($option, $search) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($option as $s) {
        if (stripos($s, $search) !== false) {  //stripos is case insensitive, strpos() is case sensitive
            array_push($result, $s);
        }
    }
    return $result; 
}

function ja_ajax_search() {
    $search_key = $_POST['search'];

    add_filter('posts_where', 'title_filter', 10, 2);

    $results = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'     => array('travel'),
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        's' => stripslashes($_POST['search'])
        //'s' => $search_key,
        //'title'     => 'true',
    ));

    remove_filter('posts_where', 'title_filter', 10, 2);

    $items = array();

    if ($results->have_posts()) {
        while ($results->have_posts()) : $results->the_post();
            $items[] = get_the_title();
        endwhile;
    }

    $items = array();

    $domestic_travel = array(
        'taxonomy'     => 'domestic_travel',
        'orderby'      => 'name',
        'show_count'   => 0,
        'pad_counts'   => 0,
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'title_li'     => '',
        //'number' => '8',
        //'child_of' => '297',
        'hide_empty'   => 1
    );

    $international_travel = array(
        'taxonomy'     => 'international_travel',
        'orderby'      => 'name',
        'show_count'   => 0,
        'pad_counts'   => 0,
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'title_li'     => '',
        //'number' => '8',
        //'child_of' => '297',
        'hide_empty'   => 1
    );

    $synonyms_cat = get_categories($international_travel);
    $related_search_cat = get_categories($domestic_travel);
    $margeArray = array();
    $margeArray2 = array();
    $margeArray_twoArray = array();

    foreach ($synonyms_cat as $val) {
        $cat_id = $val->term_id;
        $cat_name = $val->name;
        $cat_slug = $val->slug;
        $margeArray[] = $cat_name;
    }
    foreach ($related_search_cat as $val_search) {
        $cat_id = $val_search->term_id;
        $val_search_name = $val_search->name;
        $cat_slug = $val_search->slug;
        $margeArray2[] = $val_search_name;
    }

    $margeArray_twoArray = array_merge($margeArray, $margeArray2);

    $items = search_auto_sugg($margeArray_twoArray, $search_key);
    wp_send_json_success($items);
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
} 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_search_site', 'ja_ajax_search' ); 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_search_site', 'ja_ajax_search' );
```

JavaScript code:

```js
jQuery(function($){
    var searchRequest;
    $('.search-autocomplete').autoComplete({
        minChars: 1,
        source: function(term, suggest){
            try { searchRequest.abort(); } catch(e){}
            searchRequest = $.post('<?=$sendurl;?>', { search: term, action: 'search_site' }, function(res) {
                suggest(res.data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You should remove in your code the 2nd `$items = array();` as it just remove all items, and nothing is sent back.